# How to optimize SQL query which returns millions of records

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

All the example used below is currently for only one Salesorganization and we may have more different salesOrganization number later in future.

I have 6 tables which has millions of records. This tables are populated by execution of SSIS package.

```
select count(*) from tmp_materials --11,02,032

select count(*) from tbl_VendorLogoData --20,41,501
select count(*) from TBL_Image_EDV --4,44,063
select count(*) from TBL_EXTPRODUCTATTRIBUTES_EDV  -- 2,06,15,572
select count(*) from TBL_Accessories_EDV --10,11,568
select count(*) from TBL_SimilarSku --64,10,408
```

I have a stored procedure which is used to select distinct records from these tables

```
SELECT  DISTINCT    'MD' AS [COMPANYCD]
                    , MAIN.MATERIAL AS [MATERIAL]
                    , ISNULL(UPPER(IMG.[lowprovider]),'')  AS [LOW_IMAGE]
                    , ISNULL(UPPER(IMG.[midprovider]), '') AS [MID_IMAGE]
                    , ISNULL(UPPER(IMG.[highprovider]), '') AS [HIGH_IMAGE]
                    , ISNULL(UPPER(VS.isLogo),'') AS [VENDOR_LOGO]
                    , ISNULL(UPPER(DS.PROVIDER), '') AS [DATASHEET]
                    , ISNULL(ACC.AccessoryMaterial, '') AS [OPT_ACC]
                    , ISNULL(UPPER(ACC.Provider), '') AS [OPT_ACC_PROVIDER]     
                    , ISNULL(SS.Similarsku, '') AS [SIMILAR_SKU]
                    , ISNULL(UPPER(SS.ProviderName), '') AS [SIMILAR_SKU_PROVIDER]
FROM            tmp_materials MAIN WITH (NOLOCK)
LEFT OUTER JOIN TBL_Image_EDV IMG WITH (NOLOCK) ON MAIN.MATERIAL = IMG.MATERIAL AND MAIN.salesOrg = IMG.SalesOrganization
LEFT OUTER JOIN TBL_EXTPRODUCTATTRIBUTES_EDV DS WITH (NOLOCK) ON MAIN.MATERIAL = DS.SKUNBR AND MAIN.salesOrg = DS.SalesOrganization
LEFT OUTER JOIN TBL_Accessories_EDV ACC WITH (NOLOCK) ON MAIN.MATERIAL = ACC.ParentSKU AND MAIN.salesOrg = DS.SalesOrganization
LEFT OUTER JOIN TBL_SimilarSku SS WITH (NOLOCK) ON MAIN.MATERIAL = SS.ParentSKU AND MAIN.salesOrg = DS.SalesOrganization
LEFT OUTER JOIN tbl_VendorLogoData VS WITH (NOLOCK) ON MAIN.MATERIAL = VS.SKU AND MAIN.salesOrg = VS.Salesorganization
WHERE           MAIN.salesOrg = @SALESORGANIZATION
                AND (CASE   WHEN IMG.MATERIAL IS NULL AND DS.SKUNBR IS NULL  AND ACC.ParentSKU IS NULL  AND SS.ParentSKU IS NULL AND VS.SKU IS NULL
                            THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) = 1
                AND DS.Provider <> 'novalue' 
                AND SS.RecordIdentifier like '%@@%'
                AND ACC.RecordIdentifier like '%@@%'
                AND ACC.accessorySku LIKE '%@@%'
```

The parameter for these procedure is `@SALESORGANIZATION` This is used to populate a report.  I am running this for multiple salesorganization values. But for one of the salesorganization it is taking more than 5 hours to generate the data.

It seems i will need to write a loop, but finding it difficult to proceed with multiple joins any suggestions?

Please advice how can i optimize this query? Thanks for your assitance.

There you have an execution plan file [SQL Execution Plan](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8Phn6L2ON9jbW5neUdwZC1MamM/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: The first thing to check is the Execution Plan

Comment: Just give me sum time to add the Execution plan, i am populating it..

Comment: Execution plan link is added in the Question, Please refer to the select statement plan.

Comment: Any further assistance, can anyone think of any solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try to include more condition to improve performance.

In all the LEFT OUTER JOIN checks include your parameter directly and try to avoid JOINDE tables using there
e.g

```
LEFT OUTER JOIN TBL_Image_EDV IMG WITH (NOLOCK) ON 
MAIN.MATERIAL = IMG.MATERIAL 
AND MAIN.salesOrg = IMG.SalesOrganization 
AND IMG.SalesOrganization=@SALESORGANIZATION
```

Add conditions in the WHERE

```
AND SS.RecordIdentifier like '%@@%'
```

should be

```
(SS.id IS NOT NULL AND SS.RecordIdentifier like '%@@%')
```

Thus you first cut the rows with no relation

UPDATE

One more idea

Try

```
INNER JOIN (select * 
                 from TBL_Accessories_EDV 
                 where RecordIdentifier like '%@@%'
                   AND accessorySku LIKE '%@@%') ACC WITH (NOLOCK) 
 ON MAIN.MATERIAL = ACC.ParentSKU AND MAIN.salesOrg = DS.SalesOrganization
```

Just to restrict amout of records you filter out later

Comment: I will try this, but i need sum concrete solution, this will reduce minutes for the execution, but since the execution is taking more than 10 hours. I want to reduce the number of hours and generate the output in around 2 or 3 hours time

Comment: How many records is returned by the select * from MAIN where MAIN.salesOrg = @SALESORGANIZATION?

Comment: Its in the question - `select count(*) from tmp_materials --11,02,032` Actually joins are multiplying the data..

Comment: I didn't ask total but average for 1 salesOrg

Comment: That's only for one SalesOrg as i have purged the other data. We can have multiple sales organization my the data providers later.

Comment: I tried this, but this is not helping me actually it still took 9 hours and 38 mins to complete. evening my transaction logs got full :(

Comment: Answer updated. Try to replace LEFT OUTER JOIN with INNER JOIN

Comment: Inner join will not fulfill my requirement to generate the data :) it will reduce the data with only matching records but unmatched records will not be fetched

Comment: You cut them later in the WHERE (AND ACC.RecordIdentifier like '%@@%'
                AND ACC.accessorySku LIKE '%@@%') so you can use INNER JOIN for the case

Comment: Thanks, but it is not providing the matching records, i have tested the query for 100 records and it is populating the output correct. I believe i will need to break down my joins and insert in temporary tables only by one. This may work... currently practicing the breakdown queries.